# Automatically sort cards based on the alphabetical order of the last name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to sort these UI cards to display in alphabetical order according to the Last names(.lname) they contain using Jquery.

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><span class="lname">John</span> <span class="fname">Ike</span></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><span class="lname">Mark</span> <span class="fname">Amos</span></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><span class="lname">Apple</span> <span class="fname">Joshua</span></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following function `Sort` sorts all `.card` with their childnode `.lname`

`localeCompare` determines whether two strings are equivalent in the current locale. [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/62b7ahzy(v=vs.94).aspx)

```js
function Sort() {
  var sortedCards = $('.card').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.lname').text().localeCompare($(b).find('.lname').text())
  })
  $('.main').remove('.card').append(sortedCards)
}

$('.sort_button').on('click',Sort)
```

```css
img {
  width: 5% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="button" class="sort_button" value="Click!">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><span class="lname">John</span> <span class="fname">Ike</span></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer(John)</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><span class="lname">Mark</span> <span class="fname">Amos</span></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer(Mark)</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><span class="lname">Apple</span> <span class="fname">Joshua</span></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer(Apple)</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```